# Chrome Extension Background, how to send captureVisibleTab to an html file to be displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Hey so i want to open a new tab when the icon button is clicked, with a screenshot of the previous page. i am trying to send an chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab screenshot to a html page so i can display the screenshot. Here is my code

Background.js

```
console.log("Background running");

var screenshot = {
    data : '',
    init : function() {
    this.initEvents();
    },

  initEvents : function () {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{
        format: "png",
        quality:100
      },function(screenshotUrl){
        screenshot.data = screenshotUrl;
        console.log(screenshotUrl);

      var newURL = "screenshot.html";
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
      });
    });

  }
}

screenshot.init();
```

screenshot.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<img src="myScreenshot.png" alt="png">
</head>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Image to text",
  "version": "0.2",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon":"baconlogo.png"
  }


}
```

How would i do this? Thanks!